# Error with multiline string inside render function

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm getting an error:

```
missing terminator: " (for string starting at line 36)
```

when I pass this string to the `func` parameter inside a `.html.eex` file:

```
<%= render ProjectName.SnippetView, "doc_ready.html",
      func: "if (smallScreen() == 'true') {
              if ($(document).height() > 750) {                                   <%#(2a)%>
                    $('.scrollTop.main').css({'display': 'flex'})
                }
              }"
%>
```

I've already tried to use `""" """`, `\` at the end of each line and `<>` to concatenate each string line (using `"` at the beginning and end of each line) but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove this part: `<%#(2a)%>`

Or if you try to interpolate inside string please use `#{}` notation.
`<% %>` is appropriate only for HTML part of `.eex` template.